# intercepting javascript files from a secured server and use local file instead

Tags: javascript, fiddler

I am trying to intercept a https request which serves a JS file and use my local file instead.
Used fiddler tool and i am able to successfully intercept all the http request served files.
But unable to do it for the https files.
Note: I have kept my JS file in a local server..I just used the direct path like C:\test\test.js

Comment: Because you can't! This would be a horrible security risk if you could do this with https. Which is why https exists in the first place, because you *can* do this to http.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you enable the **Decrypt HTTPS Traffic** option?

Fiddler2 includes the ability to decrypt, view, and modify HTTPS-secured traffic for debugging purposes. **The decryption feature is disabled by default.**
By default, the session list will show only a CONNECT tunnel through which the HTTPS-encrypted bytes flow.

Enable the traffic decryption option by clicking `Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS` and **ticking** the `Decrypt HTTPS Traffic` box.

**Update:**
You might want to send the alternate javascript from your proxy by the way (instead of changing the source to include a script file on the users local computer).

Also, as pointed out by EricLaw in the comment to this answer:
You'd also want to look at Fiddler's **AutoResponder tab** which allows you to *return files from your local disk instead of transmitting the request to the server*.
On this tab you can enter a match rule and an action string, and Fiddler will undertake the action if the request URI matches the match rule.

---

**Extra** (because of a comment that this can't be done because it would defeat the purpose of https)

> Q: The HTTPS protocol was designed to prevent traffic viewing and
>   tampering.  Given that, how can Fiddler2 debug HTTPS traffic?
>
> A: Fiddler2 relies on a "man-in-the-middle" approach to HTTPS
>   interception.  To your web browser, Fiddler2 claims to be the secure
>   web server, and to the web server, Fiddler2 mimics the web browser. 
>   In order to pretend to be the web server, Fiddler2 dynamically
>   generates a HTTPS certificate.
>
> Fiddler's certificate is not trusted by your web browser (since
>   Fiddler is not a Trusted Root Certification authority), and hence
>   while Fiddler2 is intercepting your traffic, you'll see a HTTPS error
>   message in your browser.

It's hardly a new concept by the way, [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/) can do it to as far as I can tell.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Correct. If the question was "How do I reply with a local file?" Use the AutoResponder tab to do that.