# HTTP requests trace

Tags: http, monitoring, trace, http-request

Are there any tools to trace the exact HTTP requests sent by a program?

I have an application which works as a client to a website and facilitates certain tasks (particularly it's a bot which makes automatic offers in a social lending webstite, based on some predefined criteria), and I'm interested in monitoring the actual HTTP requests which it makes.

Any tutorials on the topic?

Comment: I'm partial to http://www.charlesproxy.com.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some popular protocol/network sniffers are:

- [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) (previous the famous Ethereal)
- [Nirsoft SmartSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html) (using [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/))
- [Nirsoft SocketSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/socket_sniffer.html) (allows you to watch the WinSock activity of the selected process and watch the content of each send or receive call, in Ascii mode or as Hex Dump)
- Microsoft's [Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) (and a [list of video-tutorials here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/netmon/p/usagevideos.aspx), note video '[Advanced Filtering 2 of 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDJ94i2nvPo)' where they specifically filter on process)

Wikipedia article '[Comparison of packet analyzers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_packet_analyzers)' has a nice overview of some other tools to.

Alternatively you could also look into (man-in-the-middle) proxy tools like:

- [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)
- [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/)

Both of the above actually record/decrypt/modify/replay [HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16022285/588079) to!! You'd need to point the application you are monitoring to this proxy. If nothing else uses that proxy the log would be application/process specific and another upside to this approach is that one could also run the monitor/logger on a different machine.

Once you choose a tool, you can easily google a tutorial to go along with it.
However the core idea is usually the same: basically one sets a filter (on capture itself or display of captured data) on things like protocol, network/mac address, portno, etc. Depending on the tool, some can also filter on local application.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sniffing all the entire network just for few requests coming from only 1 program, is it really the best solution? Especially if the asker wants to try it out on the production environment.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but as far as I know, Wireshark captures everything from a chosen network interface. Is it possible to filter the requests coming from a particular program (I haven't seen such option)?

Comment: @MrYoshiji: since most computers nowadays are behind a switch (that's behind a router/gateway) not a hub, one wouldn't be sniffing the 'entire network' (but in 'worst case' only all traffic that actually reaches the computer). However I understand your point and updated my answer, also addressing the askers comment.

Comment: I tried Charles Proxy and Fiddler, and Fiddler finally did the job, as actually I needed to look into HTTPS. I've had some difficulties in configuring Charles Proxy for that purpose, but with Fiddler it went flawless. Thank you so much for your profound answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [HTTP Toolkit](https://httptoolkit.tech) (disclaimer: it's my project).

Totally automatic HTTP & HTTPS interception, with zero setup, isolated to just the code you want to debug.

You can open a browser with it, and see all the traffic from that one window immediately (but no others), or run a terminal and automatically see all traffic only from processes started from that terminal. Built-in HTTPS decryption for everything, with no risky system-wide certificates and no manual setup. Let me know what you think!